# Acessing windows schedules task from web

Tags: windows, web-services, scheduled-tasks

I need to expose the currently scheduled tasks on a windows server for a forecast tool. Is there some way to access the tasks through a webservice or some service I could install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice powershell command

Get-WinEvent -LogName "Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational"

Will get you all avaliable log info